# Changed a class name and now Netbeans 8.2 can't run any project

Tags: java, netbeans

Pretty new to programming in general and my IDE in specific, and need a bit of help.

Relevant Info:

- OS: Windows 7
- IDE: Netbeans 8.2
- Language: Java
- Build: 1.8.0_152-b16

I tried to refactor a class name in a project because it had the same name as a library, but you some reason Netbeans wouldn't let me. In my infinite wisdom, I went to the src folder and re-named the file by hand.

Ever since then, I can no longer run ANY projects in Netbeans. This includes other projects that I did not touch the class names of. The projects will still build, but get stuck loading the run infinitely and never showing the output. Happy to supply any additional info that's required.

Edit: I've also already tried clearing Netbean's cache, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sooooo... turns out my output box was just hidden and I thought the run wasn't working because all the programs I tested it with asked for user input before completing. My bad on the newbie mistake.